# Infinite sum of exponential functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\gamma >0$, and define $H:= \{ f \mid \exists r=(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \in \ell^\infty(\mathbb{Z}) : f(x)= \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} r_n e^{-2\gamma(x-n/2)^2} \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Suppose $f,g \in H$ are non-negative and $f(\lambda)=g(\lambda)$ holds for all $\lambda \in\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is an infinite countable set. Can we prove that $f=g$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer concerning the case when $\Lambda$ has an accumulation point or there is no accumulation points, but the growth of the points in $\Lambda$ is moderate enough.

Let $f\in H.$ Then
$$f(x)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty r_n(f)e^{-2\gamma(x-n/2)^2}=e^{-2\gamma x^2}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty r_n(f)\,e^{-\gamma n^2/2}\,e^{\gamma nx}\\
=e^{-2\gamma x^2}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty s_n(f)\,e^{\gamma nx},\quad s_n(f)=r_n(f)\,e^{-\gamma n^2/2}$$
For function $h\in H$ denote $M_f=\sup_n|r_n(h)|.$

Assume $f(x)=g(x)$  for $x\in \Lambda.$ Then $e^{2\gamma x^2}f(x)-e^{2\gamma x^2}g(x)=0$ for $x\in \Lambda.$
Thus
$$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty [s_n(f)-s_n(g)]\,e^{\gamma nx}=0,\quad x\in \Lambda$$ Consider the function
$$u(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty [s_n(f)-s_n(g)]\,e^{\gamma nz},\quad z\in \mathbb{C}$$
The series is uniformly convergent on bounded subsets of the complex plane due to
$$|s_n(f)-s_n(g)|\,|e^{\gamma nz}|\le [M(f)+M(g)]\,e^{-\gamma n^2/2}e^{\gamma n{\rm Re}(z)}\quad (*)$$
Hence  $u(z)$ is an entire function, which vanishes on $\Lambda. $ If $\Lambda$ has an accumulation point, then $u=0,$ which implies $f=g.$

**Remark**  Assume the set $\Lambda$ has no accumulation points. By $(*)$ it can be shown that the entire function $u(z)$ satisfies
$$|u(z)|\le Ce^{\gamma|z|^2/2}$$ thus is of [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type) less than or equal $2.$ Therefore if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda_n|^{-2-\delta}=\infty$$ for a number $\delta>0,$ the function $u$ vanishes identically, and the conclusion follows.